# asp.net c# Change gridview row color after updating data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, row

I'm working on *asp.net* project and I am using a GridView with `SqlDataSource`. 
I have edit enabled on the GridView, so I want the row color to be changed after admin edit and update the row. How can I do that?

Comment: Tip: Please back up your question with some source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have tried everything and nothing seems to work for me, so what I did is i added a new entity in database and i named it Edited
Then I set visibility of Edited to false in Gridview and when ever update is done it inserts 1 to Edited

And i added this code to RowDataBound

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
          DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
          if (drv["ColumnName"].ToString().Equals("Something"))
          {
              e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
          }


}
```

I know it's probably a bad way to do it but it works

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following:

Create a property to record the last row you edit and remain state by `ViewState`:

```
public int LastEditRowIndex
{
    get { return (int)ViewState["LastEditRowIndex"]; }
    set { ViewState["LastEditRowIndex"] = value; }
}
```

Assign default value in case `NullPointer`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LastEditRowIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

Then record the edited row index whenever updating is done:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    LastEditRowIndex = GridView1.EditIndex;
}
```

Finally, change *CSS* on `RowDataBound` event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex == LastEditRowIndex)
        e.Row.CssClass = "bg-color-red";
}
```

Don't forget add the style in your Style Sheet:

```
.bg-color-red
{
    background-color: Red;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Nest an `<AlternatingRowStyle>` element between the opening and closing tags of your GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" >
    <Columns>
    </Columns>

    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="DarkRed" 
      ForeColor="DarkBlue"
      Font-Italic="true" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.alternatingrowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Asif it didn't work

Comment: @R.Bandi I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside GridView's `RowDataBound` event edit section:

```
 protected void Databound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && 
             YOUR GRIDVIEWID.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
      {
          YOUR GRIDVIEWID.EditRowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.YOURCOLOUR;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain what is GVSocialMedia?

Answer (score 0):

In GridView's `RowUpdating` event try this:

```
GridViewRow gvrEdit = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
gvrEdit.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, the code worked with no errors but the color doesn't change :(

Comment: In that case you need to post your code of how you are binding the gridview in `RowUpdating` method because i have tested this code and its working.

Answer (score -1):

You can have `OnRowUpdating` event and handle it.

```
void GridView1_RowUpdated(Object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:Red;");
}
```

Comment: I already did that but i keep getting some error that gridviewUpdatedEventArgs doesn't contain a definition for RowIndex